# AWS CDK - How to give server deployment group in account-2 a cross account access to artifact bucket of my codepipeline in account-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have AWS Code Pipeline for CI/CD for my application.
I am using 2 AWS accounts. Account-1 is for my repositories and pipelines and account-2 is where all the Infra/servers are.

So this is Deploy stage of my pipeline where `deploymentGroup` is created in account-2 and assigned as object `props.ec2DeploymentGroup`

```
{
    stageName: "deploy-to-" + props.targetEnvName,
    actions: [
       new codepipeline_actions.CodeDeployServerDeployAction({
          actionName: "deploy-to-"+props.targetEnvName+"-"+ props.applicationName + "-ec2",
          input: appBuildOutput,
          deploymentGroup: props.ec2DeploymentGroup
       })
        ]
  }
```

Now when my deploy stage runs it successfully tries to deploy artifacts to DeploymentGroup/Servers in account-2 but it fails at `downloadBundle` event with error

> Access Denied

And this is because my artifact bucket is in account-1 (because my pipeline is in account-1) and deployment group in account-2 don't have access to this artifact bucket in account-1.

I tried to do something like this but not sure how to get role of `props.ec2DeploymentGroup` to pass it here.

```
pipeline.artifactBucket.grantRead(whatObjectToPassHere)
```

So how should I give cross account access to artifact bucket using AWS CDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem (I had help from AWS support) my EC2 instance profile didn't have access to my artifact bucket in another account.

Which I managed in CDK using below code

```js
const ec2InstanceProfileRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'Role', 
'arn:aws:iam::'+props.targetAccountId+':role/'+props.ec2InstanceProfileName, 
{
   mutable: false,
});

pipeline.artifactBucket.grantRead(ec2InstanceProfileRole);
```